# How can I get `access token` from gcp oidc identity programatically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openid-connect

I created a OIDC provider in GCP identity. I am able to login via this OIDC and get the access token from website. The flow is that users click on `login` button, which open google login popup, after choose the `gmail` accounts from the popup. It will get the access token in the callback.

But I am looking for a way to get the user's access token programatically. If I know the `clientId`, `clientSecret` and `username/password`, whether I can get the `access token` without interactive actions?

I have read this doc https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#installation but it requires setting up a redirect url and use the code.

Is there a `management api` I can use to get the access token directly?

Comment: You can follow OAuth2 protocol with the Google endpoint: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#creatingclient

Comment: This one still requires a redirect uri `redirect_uri` which to receive the code from auth. What I am looking for is to get the token without any interactive actions.

Comment: A redirect URI is a get on a URL with query parameter. Then you have to get the access token based on the authorization code that you receive in the query parameter of your redirect URL

Comment: That's not what I want. Because I have to grab the code from the backend url and send another request to get access token. Is there a way to get the access token based on username/password directly from a API call?

Comment: AFAIK, no. You have the [service account flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#serviceaccount) if you want. But you don't use login/password for the connexion. If you try to cheat the OAuth2 protocol, you need to accept tradeoff and not convenient way to authenticate. It's designed for user authentication. You try to do it without user, So act as a user to complete the process!

Comment: Google user account OAuth requires interaction with a user (human). There is no API to bypass this. Your only option is to use Google Workplace user impersonation by a service account. That requires the users by part of Google Workplace.

Comment: That's fine to have google workspace. Do you know any API I can use if I got a google workspace user?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for Google Workspace impersonation?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Have you solved your problem? If yes, which solution led you to success?